# Why does opening a jQuery dialog change data in a separate jqGrid object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

This is some strange behavior, and I'll try to explain it as best as I can. I know it's a long shot.

I store my jqGrid objects on my page in a global object array `grids = {}`, such that myGrid would be accessed like `grids['mygrid']`. I also wrap them in an object that has a few extra properties, such as the the settings that were passed, the id of the grid, the id of the pager, etc.

With that said, I initialize all my grids at `$(document).ready()`. I also have set up a button click to show a modal jQuery dialog, which contains 3 grids. These are stored in a `div` with `display: none` at the bottom of my page.

For some reason that I can't figure out, when I click the button to open the dialog, my `grids` array gets modified, and the objects lose their properties. This occurs after the `open` event of the dialog, and only happens once. The grid still functions, but in certain situations, where I access some settings, they are gone!

There is a lot of code behind this, so I'm not sure how I would be able to show it. Does anyone know if jQuery dialog does some funny business behind the scenes when rendering the dialog that may affect a jqGrid living in it? The other grids function fine, but they are using local data, whereas this one is getting data from the server. Any advice is welcome. Thanks!

Here is an image of the the object in memory before and after the change happens. Notice the jqGridSettings field, it also makes the 'J' lowercase after it happens.

[image]

This is the beginning of the object definition in my javascript:
[image]

This would be used like so:

```
grids = { }; // Global object.
grids["myGrid"] = new ByCommonGrid(myGrid, myGrid-Pager, url, editurl);
```

Comment: Could you describe more clear the error which take place. The words "my grids array gets modified, and the objects lose their properties" can be interpreted in different way. Probably two screenshorst: a good one and a bad one can be also helpful. Which grids you use? Which `datatype` you use. If you load data from the server: do you use `loadonce`? Which jqGrid features you use: TreeGrid, Subgrids, frozen columns, grouping and so on?

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for taking a look. I added an image of the object that gets modified. This is jqGrid 3.4.1, jQuery 1.6.2, and jQueryUI v1.8.16. I use json datatype, set up as described [here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/17/38229/). Also, the only error that is thrown is from my code trying to access the non-existent fields.

Comment: Do you really mean retro version jqGrid 3.4.1 and not the current 4.3.1? What will be displayed on the ScreenShorst is absolutely unclear. What is wrong? What are `jqGridSettings` or `JqGridSettings`? Do you in debugging of the client part or the server parts of your code?

Comment: Sorry, my mind is backwards. 4.3.1 is correct. This is client side code. JqGridSettings is a field on my wrapper object for the grid, that contains the options sent in to jqGrid on initialization. Notice in the top image, it has lots of fields, colModel, colNames, etc. and in the bottom image it has just URL. This happens after I open a jQuery Dialog window, and I don't understand why.

Comment: I interpret your words, that `JqGridSettings` is the JavaScript client object. Is it so? I would first make *case-sensitive* search in your whole project for `JqGridSettings` and then for `jqGridSettings`. I suppose you have somewhere typing error. What should be correct? In general JavaScript has name conversion which is important If the first letter is capital the object must be created with `var test = new JqGridSettings;` if not you can use `var test = JqGridSettings;` What is your case? Is `JqGridSettings` - class or instance? Is it global?

Comment: JqGridSettings is a field on the wrapper JavaScript object for the grid. I will add some code for the wrapper object above. I thought typing error as well, but I only assign to that field when initializing that grid, and in no place is there a lowercase version.

Comment: You mean probably `grids["myGrid"] = new ByCommonGrid("myGrid", "myGrid-Pager", url, editurl);` instead of `grids["myGrid"] = new ByCommonGrid(myGrid, myGrid-Pager, url, editurl);`. By the way corresponding to the common name conversion all properties should have low-case character as the first characters. Global objects on the other side has typically *all* capital names like `GRIDS`. Nevertheless you posted to few information. So I don't able to help you really.

Comment: That's ok, thank you for trying. I've found other odd behaviors with this particular dialog. I'll keep digging and post any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. It didn't have anything to do internally with jqGrid, which is good.

Turns out that when a dialog is created, it executes any javascript that might be in the markup of the html you are turning into a dialog.

In this case, I was using partial views which set the global variables I use to manage my grids. When the dialog was created, these would be instantiated again, so any initialization I had done to them was lost.